# Destroy the Session File after logout

Tags: php, session

I have this code for Login where I am storing following in the session variables:

```
if($do == "login") {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["valid"] = true;
    $_SESSION["studentUniqueId"] = $user_row['studentUniqueId'];
    $_SESSION["loginName"] = $loginName;
    $_SESSION["timeout"] = $now;
}
```

Session file looks likethis:

**valid|b:1;studentUniqueId|s:5:"10001";loginName|s:13:"abc@gmail.com";timeout|s:19:"2015-07-01 18:26:32";**

Also the code for logout where I am destroying the user session:

```
    if($do == "logout") {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION = array();
                session_unset();
                session_destroy();
            }
```

After logout the session files contains:

**valid|b:0;**

Even I have used session_destroy(), after logout the session file exist with **valid|b:0;** on my servers Temp directory and  the size of the temp directory increases considerably.

I want to get rid of these files after session_destroy()/logout which is not the way now.

Is any way I am going wrong with the code.

Comment: You should not call a session_start(); twice.

Comment: in logout page, you will use unset($_SESSION);

Comment: `the size of the temp directory increases considerably` - php normally runs a cronjob to delete old session files. If your logout function works and your fundamental concern is disk space used - find out why the standard cronjob, [which looks something like this](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/8296184ffced4c876768), is missing/not running.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2 :(erasing complete session data, you can use the below code)**

```
ini_set('session.gc_max_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
```

**Edit 1 (original) :** Try this from [PHP MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Use this too
ini_set('session.gc_max_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: How is that different than the code in the question?

Comment: setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    ); <------ this line ????

Comment: Anirban can you explain me what your code is trying to do ?

Comment: How is manipulating cookies going to delete the session file on the server? There's a call to `session_destroy` already in the question.

Comment: Yup, its checking if php.ini has enabled to use cookie for storing session id, if yes its deleting(making it lifetime in negative) the cookies that holds the session data(id) plus destroying the session

Comment: Anirban: Your code didnt help to delet those session files. Nor do I feel PHP garbage collection is working out

Comment: check your server settings, where session files are being stored ?